# What is this called in JavaScript:" AnyName: function(param){//code}" (without quotes)

Tags: javascript

Full code block:

```
var create = {
    man: function(height) { // What is this line called?
        return "Generating a man. Who is " + height + " tall."
    },
    woman: function() { // And this one?
        return "Generating a woman.";
    }
};

var manC = create.man('2 feet');
console.log(manC);
```

Are they simply another way to create a function?

For clarification purposes, I do know what this code does.

Comment: It's the same thing as in `create.man = function(height){…};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called an "object literal". In your example, "man" and "woman" are two properties of the instantiated object. The values of the properties are functions.

Answer (score 0):

What's it called? I'd say it's called defining an unnamed function within an object context. The difference between that syntax (using colons)  and others you might see with equals signs is just the context in which you're defining your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Lines you ask for are actually properties of object to which you've assigned anonymous functions.